# como puedo repetir la linea de codigo pero si la excepcion fue capturada en ingresar la potencia del motor q es la segunda pregunta

Tags: java, excepciones

```
while(boleano){
       try{
       System.out.println("Ingresar año de fabricacion: ");
       int anno = sc.nextInt();   
       System.out.println("Ingresar la potencia del motor:");
       int potenciaMotor1= sc.nextInt();
       boleano = false;
       sc.nextLine();
        vehiTerre[i]= new VehiculosTerrestres(co,denominacion,anno,potenciaMotor1);
       }catch(InputMismatchException ex){
           System.out.println("Error!!: " + ex.getMessage());
            sc.nextLine();
            boleano=true;
       }
      }
```

Comment: Que tal Juan tu pregunta esta un poco confusa, podrías complementar con la problemática que deseas resolver, te invito a leer [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hola, puedes expandir mas la pregunta por favor, es confusa.

Comment: lo que quiero saber  es cuando me salga error me vuelva a formular la segunda pregunta q no comienze desde la primera

Comment: Estaría bien que pusieses un ejemplo o expandieses tu pregunta para aclararnos.

Comment: @juancruznomberto, si el error lo da solo si responden mal la segunda pregunta, entonces ¿para qué metes la primera pregunta dentro del `while`?

Comment: no lo que yo queria es hacer varias preguntas dentro de try catch para no hacerle a cada pregunta un try catch

Comment: por ejemplo si una tercera pregunta o cuarta preguntas conteste  mal me vuelva a preguntar desde esa tercera o cuarta pregunta y no desde la primera